# Not able to update column in sqlite db using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am not able to append objects into the db column. I am using sqlalchemy for this with python.
I have a track_zone function which runs in a for loop, up on event I want the status of the zone and current datetime appended
into the trigger_dates column, which is not happening. Everyting else is working fine. But the trigger_dates column is always empty.
If I print the trigger_date it is showing value like: [{'Active': datetime.datetime(2023, 7, 2, 6, 56, 10, 596339)}], but not updating it
into the db column.
Please need help here, if someone can figure out what is wrong here.

Here is the column defination in the Zone model and the track_zone function.

```
class Zone(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'zones'
    ...
    trigger_dates = Column(JSON, default=[])
```

```
def track_zone():
    # Retrieve active and pending zones with a zone count less than 4
    active_zones = session.query(Zone).filter(
        Zone.status.in_(['Active', 'Pending']),
        Zone.zonecount < 4
    ).all()

    for zone in active_zones:
        quote = session.query(Quotes).filter_by(script_name=zone.script_name, exchange=zone.exchange).order_by(
            Quotes.date_updated.desc()).first()
        if quote is None:
            continue

        high = quote.High
        low = quote.Low

        # Prepare the message with zone details for logging or notifications
        msg = ""
        for key, value in zone.__dict__.items():
            if key != "_sa_instance_state":
                msg += f"{key}: {value}\n"

        
        event_trigger = False
        # Zone is pending
        if zone.status == "Pending":
            if zone.zone_type == "long":
                # Check if quote.Low triggers the proximal line
                if quote.Low <= zone.Proximal_line:
                    zone.zonecount += 1
                    zone.status = "Active"
                    send_telegram_msg("Zone Activated\n" + msg)
                    event_trigger = True
                # Check if quote.Low triggers the distal line
                elif quote.Low <= zone.Distal_line:
                    zone.status = "Dead"
                    send_telegram_msg("Zone Violated\n" + msg)
                    event_trigger = True


        # Update the zone in the database
        if event_trigger:
            #zone.trigger_dates = zone.trigger_dates  # Update the trigger_dates column in the database
            zone.triggered_at = datetime.now()
            zone.trigger_dates.append({zone.status:datetime.now()})
            print(zone.trigger_dates)
            session.add(zone)
            session.commit()
```

I tried appending the value by .append method. Which should append it into the trigger_dates column. But it is always showing as [] (empty list)